# need code : using 6 different Gaussian classifier to classify the accuracy IRIS data set

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, gaussian

1 Cross Validation Data Design
The Iris dataset is composed of 150 samples of 4-dimensional vectors with 1 integer label. There are 3
distinct labels, and there are exactly 50 samples per label. We first want to 5-fold cross validation as
follows:

1. For class 1, split data into 5 folds: sample numbers 1-10, 11-20, 21-30, 31-40, and 41-50, and they are named as f11, f12, f13, f14, and f15, respectively.
2. For class 2, its folds are f21, f22, f23, f24, and f25.
3. For class 3, its folds are f31, f32, f33, f34, and f35.
4. Create a training data set by R1 = {f11, . . ., f14, f21, . . ., f24, f31, . . ., f34 }, and a test set by T1 = {f15, f25, f35 }.
5. Use R1 to train the above 6 Gaussian classifiers, calculate the accuracy on T1.
6. Repeat the above with R2-R5 and T2-T5, to obtain 5 accuracies.
7. Find the average accuracies, and determine the best Gaussian classifier for Iris dataset.

2 Support Vector Machines
The hyperparamters of SVM are C (non-separability) and kernel-specific parameters. Use 5-fold cross
validation to

1. Determine the best C and degree (order, rank, etc.) of the polynomial kernel functions.
2. Determine the best C and the standard deviation of the Gaussian kernel function (or called

paramter of RBF kernel).
These hyperparameter selection process is called grid search because the combinations of discrete param-
eter selection constitute a grid in a multidimensional vector space, and we look into every grid to find
the optimal hyperparameter set.
The critical design issue is the selection of discretizing continuous parameter space: for example, the
usual choice of C = {1, 10, 100, . . .}.

Comment: What is your **question**?

Comment: I am new to machine learning, so here is the assignment professor. i need code in phyton. if you can help me this regards

Comment: Welcome to SO, which nevertheless is *not* a code writing service; you are very welcome to share what you have tried so far, and any *specific* points where you may need help. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).